# Overlay hover effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't solve this problem, i want to make overlay hover effect, when the mouse on top of image, will have a layer and text come out. But now it can't, there have 7 images, when the mouse touch them, all image will have overlay effect at the same time, and are not disappear. Thank you so much.

html

```
<article class="col-md-4 isotopeItem sm">
                                <div class="portfolio-item">
                                    <div class="content-item">
                                    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">
                                        <img src="img/Case Study/Hotel-Kitchen-Equipment.jpg" alt="Kitchen" style="width:360px;height:292px;">
                                        <div class="overlay"></div>
                                        <div class="corner-overlay-content">Kitchen</div>
                                        <div class="overlay-content">
                                            <p>Kitchen</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </article>
```

css

```css
.portfolio-items article img {width:100%;} 

.portfolio-item {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
 
}
.portfolio-item img {
 -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
 -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
 -o-transition: all 300ms linear;
 -ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
 transition: all 300ms linear;
 background: #fff;
 opacity:0.9; 
}

.portfolio-item .portfolio-desc {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 color: rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.7);
}
.portfolio-item:hover .portfolio-desc {
 padding-top: 20%;
 height: 100%;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out 0s;
 opacity: 1;
}

.portfolio-item .portfolio-desc a {
 color: #ED502E;
}
.portfolio-item .portfolio-desc a:hover {
 /*text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);*/
 text-decoration: none;
}
.portfolio-item .portfolio-desc .folio-info {
 top:-20px; 
 padding: 30px;
 height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.portfolio-item:hover .folio-info{
 height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out 0s;
 top:-10px;
}


.portfolio-item .portfolio-desc .folio-info h5 {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 
}
.portfolio-item .portfolio-desc .folio-info p {
 
 font-size: 12px;
}
.content-item{
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
 
}
.overlay{
    border-bottom: 76px solid #000000;
    border-left: 360px solid #000000;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: .65;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    transition: all .9s ease-out;
    width: 0;
  }
:hover .overlay{
    border-bottom: 292px solid #000000; 
    border-left: 360px solid #000000;
    transition: all .9s ease-out;
  }
  .corner-overlay-content{
    bottom: 26px;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    right: 114px;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  :hover .corner-overlay-content{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .10s ease-out;
  }
  .overlay-content{
    bottom: 0;
    color: #333;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: all .10s ease-out;
}
.overlay-content p{
    color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    right: 114px;
    font-size: 40px;
    bottom: 124px;
}

:hover .overlay-content{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<article class="col-md-4 isotopeItem sm">
         <div class="portfolio-item">
          <div class="content-item">
          <a href="@">
           <img src="img/Case Study/Hotel-Kitchen-Equipment.jpg" alt="Kitchen" style="width:360px;height:292px;">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
             <div class="corner-overlay-content">Kitchen</div>
             <div class="overlay-content">
              <p>Kitchen</p>
              </div>
          </a>
            </div>
         </div>
        </article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

CSS

```
.portfolio-items article img {
  width: 100%;
}

.portfolio-item {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.portfolio-item img {
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
  transition: all 300ms linear;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.portfolio-item .portfolio-desc {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.7);
}
.portfolio-item:hover .portfolio-desc {
  padding-top: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out 0s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.portfolio-item .portfolio-desc a {
  color: #ED502E;
}
.portfolio-item .portfolio-desc a:hover {
  /*text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);*/
  text-decoration: none;
}
.portfolio-item .portfolio-desc .folio-info {
  top: -20px;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.portfolio-item:hover .folio-info {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out 0s;
  top: -10px;
}

.portfolio-item .portfolio-desc .folio-info h5 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.portfolio-item .portfolio-desc .folio-info p {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.content-item {
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.overlay {
  border-bottom: 76px solid #000000;
  border-left: 360px solid #000000;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: .65;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  transition: all .9s ease-out;
  width: 0;
}
.content-item:hover .overlay {
  border-bottom: 292px solid #000000;
  border-left: 360px solid #000000;
  transition: all .9s ease-out;
}
.corner-overlay-content {
  bottom: 26px;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 114px;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
  font-size: 40px;
}
.content-item:hover .corner-overlay-content {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .10s ease-out;
}
.overlay-content {
  bottom: 0;
  color: #333;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: all .10s ease-out;
}
.overlay-content p {
  color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 114px;
  font-size: 40px;
  bottom: 124px;
}

.content-item:hover .overlay-content {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
```

you should not use :hover directly. make use of container and on mouse over it trigger the effect.

[link for reference](https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/gRRxWB)

hope this helps..